# Multiple executables from makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile that will compile a simple simulated Real time operating system written in c.

The directory structure looks something like this

```
 **KB**

     SOURCE
     -------
         - Keyboard.c (helper process)
     Incl
     --------
         - Include files needed by keyboard.c

    **CRT**

     SOURCE
     -------
         - crt.c (helper process)
     Incl
     --------
         - Include files needed by crt.c

    **RTX**

    SOURCE
    -------
       - SOURCE Files

    INCLUDE
    --------
       - Include Files
```

The RTX requires that the helper processes be compiled into two executable, it then uses these executable to run.

I have no idea on how to generate three different executable in the same Makefile, or even on how to include the files in the different include files for even one executable. I've never created a makefile before and am having problems following tutorials online.

Here is what I have so far for the RTX (how do I add in different paths?)

```
#For RTX Exexutable
OBJS = api.o init_table.o k_rtx.o msg.o pcb.o queue.o user_proc.o main.o

iRTX-G29 : $(OBJS)
    gcc -o iRTX-G29 $(OBJS)

api.o : api.h
    gcc -c api.c
init_table.o : init_table.h
    gcc -c init_table.c
k_rtx.o : unistd.h string.h k_rtx.h
    gcc -c k_rtx.c
main.o : fcntl.h sys/mman.h sys/wait.h stdio.h stdio.h sys/types.h sys/ipc.h sys/shm.h errno.h string.h stdlib.h signal.h k_rtx.h buffer.h global.h
    gcc -c main.c
msg.o : msg.h
    gcc -c msg.c
queue.o : queue.h
    gcc -c queue.c
user_proc.o : user_proc.h
    gcc -c user_proc.c
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a pretty simple layout. 1) where is the makefile? 2) where do you want the object files (`msg.o`) and the executables (iRTX-G29)? 3) Do these three branches depend on each other (e.g. does RTX need `Keyboard.h` or `crt.h`)?

Comment: the makefile is in the main directory called project. The "Project" directory contains the directory RTX, KB and CRT. Each directory contains a source and a header folder where the source and header files are located. The makefile should generate three executables one for the keyboard, one for the crt and one for the RTX itself.

Comment: The RTX executable needs the KB and CRT executables to run, but does not need the header files. Each executable is a different process.

Comment: One more question: which version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`.)

Comment: I'm using 3.81. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 4):

First let's simplify your existing makefile. You have many object rules that have the same form:

```
msg.o : msg.h
    gcc -c msg.c
```

A cleaner way to write it is like this:

```
msg.o : msg.c msg.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

(I've added the dependency `msg.c`, put in some [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and specified the name of the output.) Now that all of these object rules look alike, we can make a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) for this, but I'll separate the header dependency for now because `main.o` doesn't depend on `main.h`:

```
api.o : api.h
init_table.o : init_table.h
k_rtx.o : unistd.h string.h k_rtx.h
main.o : fcntl.h sys/mman.h sys/wait.h stdio.h stdio.h sys/types.h sys/ipc.h sys/shm.h errno.h string.h stdlib.h signal.h k_rtx.h buffer.h global.h
msg.o : msg.h
queue.o : queue.h
user_proc.o : user_proc.h

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Most of these objects have a header dependency, so we can separate those out and make it a little shorter:

```
api.o init_table.o k_rtx.o msg.o queue.o user_proc.o : %.o : %.h

k_rtx.o : unistd.h string.h
main.o : fcntl.h sys/mman.h sys/wait.h stdio.h stdio.h sys/types.h sys/ipc.h sys/shm.h errno.h string.h stdlib.h signal.h k_rtx.h buffer.h global.h

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

This will work within RTX/, but to get it to work when executed in the parent directory, we have to change a couple of things. I'll assume that there is a danger of filename collision (i.e. there is a `main.c` in RTX/, and a *different* `main.c` in CRT/, so we mustn't get the `main.o`s mixed up). So let's keep the RTX object files in RTX/ (and I'll take `main.o` out of the object list for convenience, and omit the `sys/***` dependencies because I don't know where you keep `sys/`). And this answer is getting long, so I'll fold in the other executables and a master target to build them all:

```
# This is the first target, so it will be the default: run "make", and you'll get this.
.PHONY: all
all: iRTX-G29 iCRT-G29 iKBD-G29
    @echo all done

#For RTX Executable
RTX_OBJS = $(addprefix RTX/, api.o init_table.o k_rtx.o msg.o pcb.o queue.o user_proc.o)
iRTX-G29 : $(RTX_OBJS) RTX/main.o

# This is a little clumsy, but it can't (easily) be helped.
RTX/k_rtx.o : RTX/unistd.h RTX/string.h
RTX/main.o : $(addprefix RTX/, fcntl.h stdio.h stdio.h errno.h string.h stdlib.h signal.h k_rtx.h buffer.h global.h)

#Now we can throw in the CRT and Keyboard executables:

CRT_OBJS = $(addprefix CRT/, this.o that.o theOther.o)
iCRT-G29 : $(CRT_OBJS) CRT/main.o

CRT/this.o: CRT/whatever.h

KBRD_OBJS = $(addprefix SOURCE/, red.o green.o blue.o)    
iKBD-G29 : $(KBRD_OBJS) SOURCE/main.o

SOURCE/green.o: SOURCE/chlorophyll.h

# Now for the stuff common to all three

iRTX-G29 iCRT-G29 iKBD-G29 :
    gcc -o $@ $^

$(RTX_OBJS) $(CRT_OBJS) $(KBRD_OBJS): %.o : %.h

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

In makefile you can write target that not correspond to real file:

```
all: executable1 executable2

executable1: a.o b.o
<TAB HERE>gcc -o $@ $^

executable2: c.o d.o
<TAB HERE>gcc -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea on how to generate three different executable in the same Makefile, or even on how to include the files in the different include files for even one executable.

This is the perfect time to start using automake. [Sarah George](http://www.developingprogrammers.com/index.php/2006/01/05/autotools-tutorial/) has written a good tutorial.

Comment: I should probably mention that I am required to write a makefile by hand =[